# Calculating Difference In Rotation Between Two Images of Different Quality

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-rotation

The goal is replace all low resolution images by referring to a repository of high resolution images.

I was able to replace the images, but I noticed that the images were rotated and I also need to reflect changed in the images that I am adding. Also, there is no pattern for changing the rotation of the images. The rotation of the image was correct manually and no records were made for almost 50% of the Images.

I was unable to find a way to calculate the rotation since the images were of different quality (same WIDTHxHEIGHT, but different file size)

The following is one of the cases that need to be resolved:

Original Low Quality Image

[image]

Added High Quality Image [image]

Comment: why not convert everythig to low quality before doing comparaison ?

Comment: @phoenixstudio interesting idea, I can just make the two images the same and then try rotating until i reach the case of two identical images. But the issue here is how do you reduce an image resolution. The only real value i have is the size of the image file.

Comment: you can use any technique (worst case "downsampling"), and try to compare them not pixel by pixcel(worst case A - B ), for example you can create 50px* 50px and it should also work since you are as humain able to tell even if they were just icons of 50x50

Answer (score 0):

Like phoenixstudio said, first downsample the images to the same size. With OpenCV, you can do this with the [resize function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize).

Then compare rotations of the images. Beware that even if the images came from the same high resolution source, it is unlikely that they will be bit-identical for the correct rotation. Different downsampling method or distortion from lossy compression could create a minor difference in pixel values. So compare with a tolerance like `mean((A - B)^2) < tol`.

Another thought: If these are JPEG images, there might be a rotation field in the EXIF metadata, which might help: see https://jdhao.github.io/2019/07/31/image_rotation_exif_info/